# unattended cygwin base + apt-cyg install

Tags: cygwin

I would like to do an unattended (i.e. using no GUI) cygwin base install, also including the `svn` package so I can install `apt-cyg`

**Question**: How can I do this?

Note: After I have done the base + svn install, I will pull in the packages I need with `cyg-apt`, e.g.

```
svn --force export http://apt-cyg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ /bin/
chmod +x /bin/apt-cyg
```

Then install packages, e.g.

```
apt-cyg install vim
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up doing this to install Base + svn:

```
set CYG_SITE=http://sourceware.mirrors.tds.net/pub/sourceware.org/cygwin/
setup.exe -R c:\dev\cygwin\root -q -C Base -P subversion -n -d -O -s %CYG_SITE%
```

Take a look at `setup.exe --help` for the meaning of the options.